# How to disable KafkaUtils override my kafka topic in spark job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

Part of my spark job:

```
 val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
   "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
   "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
   "group.id" -> "mytopic",
 )

 try {
   val inputStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](Array(inputTopic), kafkaParams))
   val processedStream = inputStream.map(record => record.value)
   processedStream.print()
   ssc.start
   ssc.awaitTermination
 } finally {
   ...
 }
```

I got the following log:

```
2018-10-23 14:35:26 WARN  KafkaUtils:66 - overriding executor group.id to spark-executor-mytopic
```

How to disable the topic override?
Any comments welcomed. Thanks